# show acronym in bold

Tags: formatting, bold, acronyms

I'm using the `acronym` package. The first time I use the acronym the full name will be written. What I would like is to have the acronym in bold while the full name is NOT in bold is that possible?

Ex:
I need: Kalman Filter (**KF**) but `\textbf{\ac{KF}}` gives: **Kalman Filter (KF)**

Answer (score 4):

The format the first appearance of the short version is set with is `\acfsfont`. You can simply redefine it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acronym}
\renewcommand*\acfsfont{\textbf}
\newacro{KF}{Kilman Filter}

\begin{document}

\ac{KF} \ac{KF}

\end{document}
```

[image]